# Ranking a record based on sort order of multiple related records in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql

I have two tables, plus a matching table. For argument's sake, let's call them Recipes and Ingredients. Each Recipe should have at least one Ingredient, but may have many. Each Ingredient can be used in many Recipes.

```
 Recipes           Ingredients       Match
 ===============   ===============   ===============
 ID   int          ID   int           RecipeID     int
 Name varchar      Name varchar       IngredientID int
```

Sample data:

```
 Recipes           Ingredients       Match (shown as CDL but stored as above)
 ===============   ===============   ===============
 Soup              Chicken           Soup:        Chicken, Tomatoes
 Pizza             Tomatoes          Pizza:       Cheese, Chicken, Tomatoes
 Chicken Sandwich  Cheese            C. Sandwich: Bread, Chicken, Tomatoes
 Turkey Sandwich   Bread             T. Sandwich: Bread, Cheese, Tomatoes, Turkey        
                   Turkey
```

Here's the problem: I need to sort the **Recipes** based on the name(s) of their **Ingredients**. Given the above sample data, I would need this sort order for recipes:

```
 Turkey Sandwich    (First ingredient bread, then cheese)
 Chicken Sandwich   (First ingredient bread, then chicken)
 Pizza              (First ingredient cheese)
 Soup               (First ingredient chicken)
```

Ranking the recipes by the *first* ingredient is straightforward:

```
 WITH recipesranked AS (
    SELECT Recipes.ID, Recipes.Name, Recipes.Description,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Ingredients.Name) AS SortOrder
    FROM
        Recipes
        LEFT JOIN Match ON Match.RecipeID = Recipes.ID
        LEFT JOIN Ingredients ON Ingredients.ID = Match.IngredientID
    )
 SELECT   ID, Name, Description, MIN(SortOrder)
 FROM     recipesranked
 GROUP BY ID, Name, Description;
```

Beyond that, I'm stuck. In my example above, this almost works, but leaves the two sandwiches in an ambiguous order.

I have a feeling that the `MIN(SortOrder)` should be replaced by something else, maybe a correlated subquery looking for the non-existence of another record in the same CTE, but haven't figured out the details.

Any ideas?

(It is possible for a Recipe to have no ingredients. I don't care what order they come out in, but the end would be ideal. Not my main concern at this point.)

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

**Update:** I added an SQL Fiddle for this and updated the example here to match:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38258/2

**Update:** I have a sneaking suspicion that if there is a solution, it involves a cross-join to compare every combination of Recipe/Ingredient against every other, then filtering that somehow.

Comment: Any chance you could set this up on SQL Fiddle?

Comment: i don't really follow what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: You can use this solution as your starting point  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209768/sql-split-function-and-ordering-issue/19209883#19209883

Comment: @SpectralGhost, added the fiddle. Please fiddle away. :)

Comment: @AnupAgrawal, I'm not sure I understand how that answer relates. I'm not storing anything in comma-delimited strings. The example shows comma-delimited form for the Match table only to save space, those matches are separate records.

Comment: Thanks for adding the fiddle. I was thinking of creating a CTE with data shown as Match table and use the above SO solution to sort the recipe.

Comment: Is SQLCLR available for you to use? You could concatenate the ingredients in a user defined aggregate and sort recipes by that.

Comment: This is an application logic and should not be implemented in the DB

Comment: MattStephenson, SQLCLR is available, but not the right solution here, since this isn't a simple function call.

Moho, by that logic, ALL use of ORDER BY would be inappropriate. I'll grant it's more complicated than your average sort, but MSSQL is built for joining and sorting. Doing this in the BLL would require shuttling all of the dependent records out of the database just to identify the sort order of the primary records -- highly inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will give you what you want (based on your supplied Fiddle)

```
-- Show recipes ranked by all their ingredients alphabetically
 WITH recipesranked AS (
    SELECT Recipes.ID, Recipes.Name, SortedIngredients.SortOrder
    FROM
        Recipes
        LEFT JOIN Match ON Match.RecipeID = Recipes.ID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
          SELECT ID, Name, POWER(2.0, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name Desc)) As SortOrder 
          FROM Ingredients) AS SortedIngredients
         ON SortedIngredients.ID = Match.IngredientID
    )
 SELECT   ID, Name, SUM(SortOrder)
 FROM     recipesranked
 GROUP BY ID, Name
 -- Sort by sum of the ingredients. Since the first ingredient for both kinds 
 -- of sandwiches is Bread, this gives both of them the same sort order, but
 -- we need Turkey Sandwiches to come out first between them because Cheese
 -- is it's #2 sorted ingredient, but Chicken is the #2 ingredient for
 -- Chicken sandwiches.
 ORDER BY SUM(SortOrder) DESC;
```

It just uses POWER to ensure that the most significant ingredients get weighted first.

This will work for any number of recipes and up to 120 ingredients (in total)

Will not work if recipes contain duplicate ingredients, though you could filter those out if they could occur

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, this would work for up to 9 total ingredients per recipe (before int blows up) and no more than 10 recipes with the same ingredient per query (before the ingredient's 10's place overflows).

Comment: Changed to use powers of 2.  POWER IS operating on float, so it should work with up to 120 ingredients in total, regardless of the number of recipes

Comment: I ended up using a custom IComparer<> in C#, this solution didn't quite work for my application (where the data are far more complex than recipes). But this is the closest to a viable solution, and probably would work for other situations, so I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

Binary Flag version:

```
;with IngredientFlag( IngredientId, Flag )
as
(
    select
        i.id Ingredient
        , POWER( 2, row_number() over ( order by i.Name desc ) - 1 )
    from
        Ingredients i
)
, RecipeRank( RecipeId, Rank )
as
(
    select
        m.RecipeID
        , row_number() /* or rank() */ over ( order by SUM( flag.Flag ) desc )
    from
        Match m
        inner join IngredientFlag flag
         on m.IngredientID = flag.IngredientId
    group by
        m.RecipeID
)

select
    RecipeId
    , Name
    , Rank
from
    RecipeRank rr
    inner join Recipes r
     on rr.RecipeId = r.id
```

Str Concat version:

```
    -- order the ingredients per recipe
;with RecipeIngredientOrdinal( RecipeId, IngredientId, Name, Ordinal )
as
(
    select
    m.RecipeID
    , m.IngredientID
    , i.Name
    , Row_Number() over ( partition by m.RecipeId order by i.Name ) Ordinal
    from
      Match m
      inner join Ingredients i
       on m.IngredientID = i.id
)
    -- get ingredient count per recipe
, RecipeIngredientCount( RecipeId, IngredientCount )
as
(
    select
    m.RecipeID
    , count(1)
    from
      Match m
    group by
        m.RecipeID
)
    -- recursively build concatenated ingredient list per recipe
    -- (note this will return incomplete lists which is why I include
    --  'generational' in the name)
, GenerationalConcatenatedIngredientList( RecipeId, Ingredients, IngredientCount )
as
(
    select
        rio.RecipeID
        , cast( rio.Name as varchar(max) )
        , rio.Ordinal
    from
        RecipeIngredientOrdinal rio
    where
        rio.Ordinal = 1

    union all

    select
        rio.RecipeID
        , cil.Ingredients + rio.Name
        , rio.Ordinal
    from
        RecipeIngredientOrdinal rio
        inner join GenerationalConcatenatedIngredientList cil
         on rio.RecipeID = cil.RecipeId and rio.Ordinal = cil.IngredientCount + 1
)
    -- return row_number or rank ordered by the concatenated ingredients list
-- (don't need to return Ingredients but shown for demonstrative purposes)
, RecipeRankByIngredients( RecipeId, Rank, Ingredients )
as
(
    select
        cil.RecipeId
        , row_number() over ( order by cil.Ingredients ) -- or rank()
        , cil.Ingredients
    from
        GenerationalConcatenatedIngredientList cil
        inner join RecipeIngredientCount ric
         on cil.RecipeId = ric.RecipeId 
                     -- don't forget to filter for only the completed ingredient lists
                     --  and ignore all intermediate values
                     and cil.IngredientCount = ric.IngredientCount
)

select * from RecipeRankByIngredients
```

Comment: String concatenation isn't an option, unfortunately. The "names" are actually quite long and numerous and are already indexed, and performance is important.

Comment: The algorithm works;  how about testing it and letting us know the performance

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you need:

```
WITH recipesranked AS (
    SELECT Recipes.ID, Recipes.Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Ingredients.Name) AS SortOrder,
    Rank () OVER (partition by Recipes.Name ORDER BY Ingredients.Name) as RankOrder
     FROM
         Recipes
         LEFT JOIN Match ON Match.RecipeID = Recipes.ID
         LEFT JOIN Ingredients ON Ingredients.ID = Match.IngredientID
)
  SELECT   ID, Name,SortOrder, RankOrder
  FROM     recipesranked
 Where RankOrder = 1
 ORDER BY SortOrder;
```

Comment: This incorrectly orders Chicken Sandwich (Bread -> Chicken)  prior to Turkey Sandwich (Bread -> Cheese)

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative way I can think of to do it, is to use dynamic sql to generate a pivot

This doesn't have the limitation on the number of ingredients that my alternative has, but doesn't exactly feel elegant!

```
DECLARE @MaxIngredients INT

SELECT @MaxIngredients = MAX(IngredientCount)
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS IngredientCount
    FROM Match
    GROUP BY RecipeID
) A

DECLARE @COLUMNS nvarchar(max)
SELECT @COLUMNS = N'[1]' 

DECLARE @COLUMN INT
SELECT @COLUMN = 2

WHILE (@COLUMN <= @MaxIngredients)
BEGIN
    SELECT @COLUMNS = @COLUMNS + N',[' + CAST(@COLUMN AS varchar(19)) + N']', @COLUMN = @COLUMN + 1
END

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

SELECT @SQL = 
N'WITH recipesranked as(
SELECT *
FROM 
( 
    SELECT  M.RecipeID, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY M.RecipeID ORDER BY I.SortOrder) AS IngredientIndex, 
            I.SortOrder
    FROM    Match M
    LEFT
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) As SortOrder
        FROM Ingredients
    ) I
        ON I.ID = M.IngredientID
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MIN(SortOrder) --min here is just for the syntax, there will only be one value
    FOR IngredientIndex IN (' + @COLUMNS + N')
) AS PivotTable)
SELECT R.Name
FROM    RecipesRanked RR
JOIN    Recipes R
    ON  RR.RecipeID = R.ID
ORDER BY ' + @COLUMNS

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and use that.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetIngredients(@RecipeName varchar(200))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ingredients VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @Ingredients=NULL

    SELECT TOP 9999999
        @Ingredients = COALESCE(@Ingredients + ', ', '') + Ingredients.Name
    FROM  Recipes
    LEFT JOIN Match ON Match.RecipeID = Recipes.ID
    LEFT JOIN Ingredients ON Ingredients.ID = Match.IngredientID
    WHERE Recipes.Name=@RecipeName
    ORDER BY Ingredients.Name ASC

    return @Ingredients
END
GO


SELECT
    Recipes.Name AS RecipeName, dbo.GetIngredients(Recipes.Name) [Ingredients]
FROM  Recipes
ORDER BY [Ingredients]
```