# Xpath help needed on XML output

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I trying to use `Xpath` to get the `DataTable` Headers.

My output should be:

> ItemNum|Item|ResultCode|Status|ExtBackLinks|RefDomains|AnalysisResUnitsCost|ACRank|ItemType|IndexedURLs|GetTopBackLinksAnalysisResUnitsCost|DownloadBacklinksAnalysisResUnitsCost|DownloadRefDomainBacklinksAnalysisResUnitsCost|RefIPs|RefSubNets|RefDomainsEDU|ExtBackLinksEDU|RefDomainsGOV|ExtBackLinksGOV|RefDomainsEDU_Exact|ExtBackLinksEDU_Exact|RefDomainsGOV_Exact|ExtBackLinksGOV_Exact|CrawledFlag|LastCrawlDate|LastCrawlResult|RedirectFlag|FinalRedirectResult|OutDomainsExternal|OutLinksExternal|OutLinksInternal|OutLinksPages|LastSeen|Title|RedirectTo|Language|LanguageDesc|LanguageConfidence|LanguagePageRatios|LanguageTotalPages|RefLanguage|RefLanguageDesc|RefLanguageConfidence|RefLanguagePageRatios|RefLanguageTotalPages|CrawledURLs|RootDomainIPAddress|TotalNonUniqueLinks|NonUniqueLinkTypeHomepages|NonUniqueLinkTypeIndirect|NonUniqueLinkTypeDeleted|NonUniqueLinkTypeNoFollow|NonUniqueLinkTypeProtocolHTTPS|NonUniqueLinkTypeFrame|NonUniqueLinkTypeImageLink|NonUniqueLinkTypeRedirect|NonUniqueLinkTypeTextLink|RefDomainTypeLive|RefDomainTypeFollow|RefDomainTypeHomepageLink|RefDomainTypeDirect|RefDomainTypeProtocolHTTPS|CitationFlow|TrustFlow|TrustMetric|TopicalTrustFlow_Topic_0|TopicalTrustFlow_Value_0|TopicalTrustFlow_Topic_1|TopicalTrustFlow_Value_1|TopicalTrustFlow_Topic_2|TopicalTrustFlow_Value_2

This is the original XML:

```html
<Result Code="OK" ErrorMessage="" FullError="">
<GlobalVars FirstBackLinkDate="2012-09-21" IndexBuildDate="2018-05-24 19:47:18" IndexType="0" MostRecentBackLinkDate="2018-04-23" QueriedRootDomains="1" QueriedSubDomains="0" QueriedURLs="0" QueriedURLsMayExist="0" ServerBuild="2018-06-11 13:52:01" ServerName="BRUNO28" ServerVersion="1.0.6736.23160" UniqueIndexID="20180524194718-HISTORICAL"/>
<DataTables Count="1">
<DataTable Name="Results" RowsCount="1" Headers="ItemNum|Item|ResultCode|Status|ExtBackLinks|RefDomains|AnalysisResUnitsCost|ACRank|ItemType|IndexedURLs|GetTopBackLinksAnalysisResUnitsCost|DownloadBacklinksAnalysisResUnitsCost|DownloadRefDomainBacklinksAnalysisResUnitsCost|RefIPs|RefSubNets|RefDomainsEDU|ExtBackLinksEDU|RefDomainsGOV|ExtBackLinksGOV|RefDomainsEDU_Exact|ExtBackLinksEDU_Exact|RefDomainsGOV_Exact|ExtBackLinksGOV_Exact|CrawledFlag|LastCrawlDate|LastCrawlResult|RedirectFlag|FinalRedirectResult|OutDomainsExternal|OutLinksExternal|OutLinksInternal|OutLinksPages|LastSeen|Title|RedirectTo|Language|LanguageDesc|LanguageConfidence|LanguagePageRatios|LanguageTotalPages|RefLanguage|RefLanguageDesc|RefLanguageConfidence|RefLanguagePageRatios|RefLanguageTotalPages|CrawledURLs|RootDomainIPAddress|TotalNonUniqueLinks|NonUniqueLinkTypeHomepages|NonUniqueLinkTypeIndirect|NonUniqueLinkTypeDeleted|NonUniqueLinkTypeNoFollow|NonUniqueLinkTypeProtocolHTTPS|NonUniqueLinkTypeFrame|NonUniqueLinkTypeImageLink|NonUniqueLinkTypeRedirect|NonUniqueLinkTypeTextLink|RefDomainTypeLive|RefDomainTypeFollow|RefDomainTypeHomepageLink|RefDomainTypeDirect|RefDomainTypeProtocolHTTPS|CitationFlow|TrustFlow|TrustMetric|TopicalTrustFlow_Topic_0|TopicalTrustFlow_Value_0|TopicalTrustFlow_Topic_1|TopicalTrustFlow_Value_1|TopicalTrustFlow_Topic_2|TopicalTrustFlow_Value_2" MaxTopicsRootDomain="30" MaxTopicsSubDomain="20" MaxTopicsURL="10" TopicsCount="3">
<Row>
0|nu.nl|OK|Found|508322106|165344|508322106|-1|1|4149991|5000|512472097|3356880|59147|26204|233|3613|43|308|73|1757|4|12|False| | |True| |5|10|44|1722150| |NU - Het laatste nieuws het eerst op NU.nl|https://www.nu.nl/|nl|Dutch/Flemish|92|99.9|482980|nl,en,de|Dutch/Flemish,English,German|87,93,58|96.5,3.1,0.1|76319583|1915923|52.85.201.19|611833777|15034990|53120677|444371798|95283418|52384870|388104|53497551|5655999|552292123|102171|115787|21952|150164|49554|76|70|70|News/Breaking News|69|Sports/Resources|45|Arts/Radio|43
</Row>
</DataTable>
</DataTables>
</Result>
```

When I use this `Xpath` command in *Google Sheets*:

```
=importxml("http://enterprise.majesticseo.com/api_command?privatekey=xxx&accessToken=xxx&cmd=GetIndexItemInfo&item0=nu.nl&items=1","//DataTable"
```

I get the Row results. Which Is great but I also need the Header names in the first row of my sheet.

Comment: The output you mention in your question should be obtained by using the following XPath expression: `//DataTable/@Headers`

Comment: Thanks you, it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a short introduction to XPath :-)

With `//DataTable` you will get the full node of any `<DataTable>` (no namespaces involved here) anywhere in the XML.
It is - as a rule of thumb - better to be as specific as possible (rather use `/Result/DataTables/DataTable`). But this is not the answer to your question...

Just imagine an XML like this:

```
<root>
  <innerNode attr="1"><a>Some a content</a><b>Some b content</b></innerNode>
  <innerNode attr="2"><a>aaa</a><b>bbb</b></innerNode>
</root>
```

With `/root/innerNode` you'd get both `<innerNode>` with all content.

With `/root/innerNode[(b/text())[1]="bbb"]` you'd get just one `<innerNode>`, the one where `<b>`'s `text()` is `"bbb"`

With `/root/innerNode[@attr="1"]` you'd get the one `<innerNode>` where the attribute `attr` has a value of "2".

All three `XPath` samples bring back the full node, including sub nodes, attributes, whatever.

if you want just the value of an attribute you must ask for it:

```
(/root/innerNode/@attr)[2]
```

... returns the attribute's value of the second `<innerNode>` (the 2nd occurance actually)

```
/root/innerNode[(b/text())[1]="Some b content"]/@attr
```

... returns the attribute's value of the `<innerNode>` where the `<b>` has a `text()` 0f `"Some b content"`

### back to your question

You want to read the attribute `Headers` within the element `<DataTable>` living at `/Result/DataTables`. Just use

```
/Result/DataTables/DataTable/@Headers
```

Comment: Figured I'd ask the XML Ninja a question.  Regarding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030750/sql-server-how-to-sort-in-order-as-entered/51030779#51030779   Is there a risk of XML Parse approach changing the sequence?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti commented there :-)

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help and explanation. That was very usefull and it worked!