# XML to SQL Issue - How to get position of an element

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to get the position of an element of an XML node in sql , and it is not giving me correct results , the approach was suggested by @Shungo

This is the code :

```
declare @xmlVar xml ='
<A specVersion="2.09">
  <B id="1" type="Regular">
    <C>
      <D>
        <E actioncode="A" date="06/13/2018 09:20" />
        <E  actioncode="B" date="06/13/2018 09:20" />
      </D>
      <D>
        <E actioncode="C" date="06/13/2018 09:20" />
      </D>
    </C>
  </B>

  <B id="2" type="Regular">
    <C>
      <D>
        <E  actioncode="D" date="06/13/2018 09:20" />
      </D>
    </C>
  </B>
</A>' ;
    WITH Tally(Nmbr) AS
(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT @xmlVar.value(N'count(/A/B/C/D)','int'))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
    FROM master..spt_values --just a pre-filled table with many rows
)
SELECT Nmbr
      ,e.value(N'@actioncode[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Employee
FROM Tally
OUTER APPLY(SELECT @xmlVar.query(N'/A/B/C/D[sql:column("Nmbr")]')) AS A(ds)
OUTER APPLY ds.nodes(N'D/E') AS B(e);
```

The above query is giving wrong results :

```
1   A
1   B
1   D
2   C
3   NULL
```

Expected Output:

```
1  A
1  B
2  C
3  D
```

Any help would be appreciated . Thanks.

Comment: I am doing some mistake ... But I am not able to find it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is quite different to the one before...

As it looks, you want to take `<D>` nodes whereever they are placed. Does this help?

```
WITH Tally(Nmbr) AS
(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT @xmlVar.value(N'count(//D)','int'))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
    FROM master..spt_values --just a pre-filled table with many rows
)
SELECT Nmbr
      ,e.value(N'@actioncode[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Employee
FROM Tally
OUTER APPLY(SELECT  @xmlVar.query(N'//D').query(N'/D[sql:column("Nmbr")]')) AS B(ds)
OUTER APPLY ds.nodes(N'D/E') AS C(e);
```

The first apply will use the *deep search* (with `//D`) to get a derived XML including these nodes only. The rest is rather the same as before.

Comment: Yes as of now it is working fine , but I am looking for a generic solution , because as of now in above example ... D is present only in this level..... A->B->C->D but in real time D can be present in other child as well... like ... A->F->C->D  or ... A->F->D ... in these cases I am getting details for these D as well.. where as I want details for only this level .. A->B->C->D.

Comment: Thanks a lot  ... You seems to be an expert of it :P
I have started another question for this specific question ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51197746/xml-to-sql-issue-sql-server    
Please have a look at it when you get time .