# XML to SQL Issue - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to get position of a specific element of xml in sql script , but I am getting details for all the positions of a specific  element , where as I am looking for a particular level only.

This is the code :

```
declare @xmlVar xml ='
<A specVersion="2.09">
  <B id="1" type="Regular">
    <C>
      <D>
        <E actioncode="A" date="06/13/2018 09:20" />
        <E  actioncode="B" date="06/13/2018 09:20" />
      </D>
      <D>
        <E actioncode="C" date="06/13/2018 09:20" />
      </D>
    </C>
  </B>

  <B id="2" type="Regular">
    <C>
      <D>
        <E  actioncode="D" date="06/13/2018 09:20" />
      </D>
    </C>
    <F>
        <D>
            <E  actioncode="F" date="06/13/2018 09:20" />
        </D>
    </F>
  </B>
</A>' ;

WITH Tally(Nmbr) AS
(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT @xmlVar.value(N'count(//D)','int'))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
    FROM master..spt_values --just a pre-filled table with many rows
)
SELECT Nmbr
      ,e.value(N'@actioncode[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Employee
FROM Tally
OUTER APPLY(SELECT  @xmlVar.query(N'//D').query(N'/D[sql:column("Nmbr")]')) AS B(ds)
OUTER APPLY ds.nodes(N'D/E') AS C(e);
```

**Results of the above query :**

```
1   A
1   B
2   C
3   D
4   F
```

**Expected Output :**

```
1 A
1 B
2 C
3 D
```

I am looking for positions of all D which comes in path A->B->C->D not the one's which come in other path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this seems to be a rather easy change to your previous question. You can use the same logic, but reduce it to the path you want to see:

```
WITH Tally(Nmbr) AS
(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT @xmlVar.value(N'count(/A/B/C/D)','int'))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
    FROM master..spt_values --just a pre-filled table with many rows
)
SELECT Nmbr
      ,e.value(N'@actioncode[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Employee
FROM Tally
OUTER APPLY(SELECT  @xmlVar.query(N'/A/B/C/D').query(N'/D[sql:column("Nmbr")]')) AS B(ds)
OUTER APPLY ds.nodes(N'D/E') AS C(e);
```

### UPDATE: Get the `<B id="x">` value

As you found out, the approach above cannot move backward up to `<B>`. Try this:

```
WITH AllBs AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS B_position
          ,b.value('@id','int') AS B_id
          ,b.query('.') AS B_node
    FROM @xmlVar.nodes('/A/B') AS A(b)
)
,AllDs As
(
    SELECT AllBs.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS D_position
          ,d.query('.') AS D_node 
    FROM AllBs 
    OUTER APPLY B_node.nodes('B/C/D') AS A(d)
)
SELECT AllDs.*
      ,e.value(N'@actioncode[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Employee
FROM AllDs
OUTER APPLY D_node.nodes('D/E') AS A(e);
```

As written in my first answer, there's a tiny risk about the sort order... But the approach with the *tally table* cannot fetch the 3rd occurance, because the position within `[sql:column()]` is re-numbered with any parent. That means: The 3rd `<D>` is the 1st in the 2nd `<B>`. That's why I placed the `.query()` in between...

Comment: Can i get id of <B> along with the results ... I am using ../../@id .... but it is giving NULL.